# Dynamic timestamp for assetic?

Tags: symfony, assetic

Right now I have :

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    assets_version:      ~
    assets_version_format:  %%s?%%s
```

And My `javascripts` tag

```
assetic:
    debug:            false
    use_controller:   false
    read_from:        %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    write_to:         %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    .....
```

And guess what ? the name of the files never changes each time  I run

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

I've followed the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) without any success...

What i clearly don't want is to specify **manually** the version of the assets in the config.yml. I want the name of the file OR a special query string generated **automatically** when the file compiled file has changed (or when i run the dump command)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `assets_version` param does not control the name of the files that assetic generates. It is just a query param that is added to the url of the asset when you output it using the `asset()` function in twig. This generates urls like this:

```
/images/logo.png?v2
```

where v2 is the value of the `assets_version` param. The problem is that you must manually update this value everytime you update your assets as there is no automatic way to do that.

As for the name of the assetic file not changing when you rerun assetic:dump, this is a known issue. But you are lucky! Just three days ago a new [pull request](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/pull/297) was merged into the assetic code which just provides this functionality :-). So, you just need to update to the latest latest version of assetic and you will get this feature working.

Comment: great news thanks, the doc is not updated yet, do you know how to enable this feature ? In assetic they talk about strategy for the CacheBustingWorker. EDIT : Ok this is pending : https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/pull/119

Comment: Ah, I did not notice that configuration was pending... I hope they approve this soon